# Pysolr add throws (HTTP 500): [Reason: Task queue processing has stalled

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud, pysolr

I am using Pysolr to add data to solr. I add 100 documents at once.But i am getting the below error.

Solr responded with an error (HTTP 500): [Reason: Task queue processing has stalled for 20121 ms with 0 remaining elements to process.]

is solr has queue internally and is it filled due to high number of hits? Can I increase the size of the queue(I mean limit)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can control this time via the `solr.cloud.client.stallTime` system property.

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13975?focusedCommentId=16988216&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16988216

Comment: Any clue how you set this? Can't find any documentation on it other than it's presence in the documentation [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/using-solrj.html#timeouts)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. It should be a parameter like `-Dsolr.cloud.client.stallTime` which would normally go in solr.in.sh or solr.in.cmd. Some pointers about system properties in general can be found here: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/taking-solr-to-production.html#override-settings-in-solrconfig-xml